# Wildfly JNDI lookup AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, wildfly

I deployed an ear containing a war and a jar module on Wildfly 8.0.2.Final. I want to get AuthenticationManager within the war module via JNDI lookup, but I don't know the naming syntax. Somebody knows? Can't find any documentation about provided resources (and their JNDI name) of wildfly.

Comment: To what `AuthenticationManager` are you referring?

Comment: No Special authentication manager is specified for my security domain, so its the default one. But I don't know the default value.  JbossCachedAuthenticationManager? Or JaasSecurityManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my security domain does not specify an authenticationManager, the default one is used. Log messages of the security-subsystem told me, that JBossCachedAuthenticationManager is the default one. To get an authenticationManager via JNDI, it must be looked up at java:jboss/jaas/nameOfMyDecurityDomain 
(see here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-3255). So my code is

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jaas/databaseSd")
private JBossCachedAuthenticationManager auth;
```